# How can I number data blockwise in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to number chunks of filesets continuously, say from 1 to 3 for example.

Let's say I have the following:

```
ID | random_nr | ordering
.. | .. | ..
19 | 12 | 2
19 | 21 | 3
20 | 13 | 1*
20 | 14 | 2*
20 | 22 | 3*
21 | 15 | 1
21 | 17 | 2
.. | .. |
```

My code so far only numbers all sets right through:

```
SET @c = 0; 
SELECT
`ID`,
`random`,
(@c := @c + 1) AS "ordering"
FROM `tabelle` WHERE ...
```

How could I change it so I get the result mentioned above?
Thanks a million!!

Comment: the question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
 SELECT x.*
      , COUNT(*) ordering 
   FROM tabelle x 
   JOIN tabelle y 
     ON y.id = x.id 
    AND y.random_nr <= x.random_nr 
  GROUP 
     BY x.id
      , x.random_nr;
```

Another way is to add @curr and @prev markers to your existing query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @i = null;
SELECT
`ID`,
`random`,
(@c := IF(ID = @i, @c + 1, 1) + (@i:=ID)-ID AS "ordering"
FROM `tabelle` WHERE ...
ORDER BY ID
```

So each time the ID is *not* equal to current value of @i, then @c starts over at 1.